# Is there a more efficient way to make background position change from left to right on hover?

Tags: html, css

This is the code I currently have to make it seem as though the left border expands on hover, even though it's just the background changing. Is there a more efficient way to write this code?

edit: Efficient meaning a better way to write it.

```css
span {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, yellow 50%, black 50%);
  background-size: 200%, 100%;
  background-position: right;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

span:hover {
  background-position: left;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<span>This is some example text.</span>
```

Comment: why does it matter? it's CSS and it's not 50 lines, just a few ones. you didn't define "efficient". in what why? CPU? GPU? this code is OK.

Comment: efficient, as in a better way to write it. That way I don't have unnecessary lines. If there is a "better" way to write it I'd like to know.

Comment: it's not more "efficient", it's simply less lines. maybe more efficient in terms of the body energy saved from typing on the keyboard. you can write the `background` property in shorthand, but that is very basic and every person that learned CSS for a month knows that, so I'm guessing you're after something which will crunch is even more.

Comment: Okay, well I literally just started learning to code and I didn't know whether or not I was writing this correctly. I realize I got the outcome that I wanted, but I was trying to see if there was a different or better way to do it. I'm not worried about "saving body energy from typing", I just don't want to have redundant or useless lines that don't do anything to achieve the goal.

Comment: if you minify your CSS (through a task runner or manually) for example with [CSSO](https://github.com/css/csso) then it will optimize it anyway. so we are left with only the issue of pre-proccessed code and the number of code lines. all if ok, shorthand or not, it doesn't really matter for such tiny amount of CSS code..

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using pseudo elements for this stuff, as you can then add transforms and such to the pseudo element for better performance.

Only problem with this is that you need to wrap your span in another element, so that you can position the text over the pseudo element with z-index. Otherwise it will just cover your text.

```css
span {
  color: black;
  transition: color .5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

p::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  will-change: transform;
  z-index: 1;
}

p:hover::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

p:hover span {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p><span>This is some example text.</span></p>
```